# Python Multiprocessing - 'Queue' object has no attribute 'task_done' / 'join'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am rewriting a threaded process into a multiprocessing queue to attempt to speed up a large calculation. I have gotten it 95% of the way there, but I can't figure out how to signal when the `Queue` is empty using `multiprocessing`.

---

My original code is something like this:

```
import Queue
from threading import Thread

num_fetch_threads = 4
enclosure_queue = Queue()

for i in range(num_fetch_threads):
  worker = Thread(target=run_experiment, args=(i, enclosure_queue))
  worker.setDaemon(True)
  worker.start()

for experiment in experiment_collection:
  enclosure_queue.put((experiment, otherVar))

enclosure_queue.join()
```

And the queue function like this:

```
def run_experiment(i, q):
  while True:
    ... do stuff ...
    q.task_done()
```

---

My new code is somethings like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

num_fetch_threads = 4
enclosure_queue = Queue()

for i in range(num_fetch_threads):
  worker = Process(target=run_experiment, args=(i, enclosure_queue))
  worker.daemon = True
  worker.start()

for experiment in experiment_collection:
  enclosure_queue.put((experiment, otherVar))

worker.join() ## I only put this here bc enclosure_queue.join() is not available
```

And the new queue function:

```
def run_experiment(i, q):
  while True:
    ... do stuff ...
    ## not sure what should go here
```

---

I have been reading the docs and Google, but can't figure out what I am missing - I know that `task_done` / `join` are not part of the `multiprocessing` `Queue` class, but it's not clear what I am supposed to use.

> "They differ in that Queue lacks the task_done() and join() methods
>   introduced into Python 2.5’s Queue.Queue class." [Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

But without either of those, I'm not sure how the queue knows it is done, and how to continue on with the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) instead of managing workers manually. Pool handles dispatching tasks to workers, with convenient functions like map and apply, and supports `.close` and `.join` methods. `Pool` takes care of handling the queues between processes and processing the results. Here's how your code might look like using `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def do_experiment(exp):
    # run the experiment `exp`, will be called by `p.map`
    return result

p = Pool() # automatically scales to the number of CPUs available

results = p.map(do_experiment, experiment_collection)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: What if you need to add tasks to it..?

Comment: `apply_async` submits a task to the pool and returns a promise object that you can use to grab the result later. You can also bind a callback when calling `apply_async` to get an immediate completion notification.